# C# - Multithreading using Multiple Input Devices

Tags: c#, multithreading, input, printing

I am currently writing a C# application that will accept input from multiple USB connected input devices. Using [the Raw Input library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard), I am able to identify the input device and then complete an action based on the input device.

Example: Device A input is received as a series of keystrokes, a string is built, a database is queried using the 'built' string as a parameter, Printer A prints the results.

The issue I am having is latency when multiple devices input values at the same time. Device A input is received at the same time as Device B; Printer A prints immediately but Printer B experiences somewhat of a delay in printing. The delay is no longer than a second, but that is one second too long for this projects intended purpose. I am using barcode scanners so I will say that the input of the entire string is *lightning fast* for lack of a better quantitative measurement.

I don't think my question requires any code on my behalf but if needed to help answer the question then let me know and I can provide a snippet. I am simply looking for an example or a strategy to use to go about multithreading input to output if that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT (Adding current code):

```
private readonly RawInput _rawinput;
const bool CaptureOnlyInForeground = true;

public InputForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _rawinput = new RawInput(Handle, CaptureOnlyInForeground);
}

string Scanner1ID;
string Scanner2ID;
string Printer1IP;
string Printer2IP;

int NumberIdentifier;
string ScannedItem;
string ScannedKey;

PLabel NewLabel = New PLabel();

//Various methods are used to identify each scanner and printer, print commands are sent via the TcpClient class in conjunction with a StreamWriter.

void StartScanning(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

    _rawinput.AddMessageFilter();
    Win32.DeviceAudit();
    _rawinput.KeyPressed += OnItemScanned;
}

private void OnItemScanned(object sender, RawInputEventArg e)
{
    ScannedKey = e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName.Replace("D", "");
    if (int.TryParse(ScannedKey, out NumberIdentifier)
    {
        ScannedItem += ScannedKey;

        if (e.KeyPressEvent.VKey == 13 || ScannedItem.Length == 10)
        {
            InOutList.Items.Add(ScannedItem); //Adds to list in form
            if (e.KeyPressEvent.DeviceHandle.ToString() == Scanner1ID)
            {
                NewLabel.querySQL(ScannedItem);
                Printer1Writer.Write(NewLabel.Results);
                Printer1Writer.Flush();
             }
             else if (e.KeyPressEvent.DeviceHandle.ToString() == Scanner2ID)
            {
                NewLabel.pingSQL(ScannedHWB);
                if (Client2Printer2.Connected)
                {
                    NewLabel.querySQL(ScannedItem);
                    Printer2Writer.Write(NewLabel.Results);
                    Printer2Writer.Flush();
                }    
            }

            ScannedItem = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I may have left something out but hopefully this is enough.

Comment: A few questions...  Does device A always go to printer A, or can it go to printer B?  Does the Raw input library support multiple threads?  Because conceivably you could set up each device on its own thread.  If the answer to the first question is no, you could conceivably use threads to read, and then some kind of `ConcurrentQueue<>` to dispatch to the printers.

Comment: It's not possible to answer in a simple SO answer - you're either looking for a tutorial (which is off-topic) and would require a lot of detail on how to set something up (following detailed requirements) or you need to handle problems with your current code (which is not included so it's impossible to suggest changes).

Comment: It may help to see how you are currently handling your input devices. I would envision you would need a single primary control thread and a thread for each device: 1. ScannerA, 2. ScannerB, 3. PrinterA, 4. PrinterB each of the Scanner device threads calls back to the primary control thread passing a value. The primary control thread passes that value off to the related Printer thread. Or each Scanner thread has a reference to the related Printer thread that it could call directly to instead of routing through the primary control thread.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Device A will always print to Printer A and so-on. Raw Input does support multithreading, would providing my current code help at all?

Comment: @DelKirksey, immensely :)

Comment: Adding now guys (or girls) @Moo-Juice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article you link

> Each window whose handle is associated with a registered device as described in the previous section must therefore check the messages it receives and take appropriate action when a WM_INPUT one is detected.

Windows message processing is a form of cooperative multi-tasking.  A new message cannot be processed from the message queue until the current one returns from processing.

If your code is responding to WM_INPUT by doing whatever it needs to in the database, *no other events* can process until that is done.

You can solve this by using a producer/consumer pattern.  Have your code that handles WM_INPUT put information necessary for processing into a structure such as a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and have a separate thread read from the BlockingCollection and do the work.

Depending on your needs, you might have one BlockingCollection per raw input device, or just a single one.  If the latter, part of the information put into the BlockingCollection would probably be an identifier of the raw device that generated the input.

Comment: Voila.  This is what I was thinking might be happening.

Comment: Yep.  Your OnItemScanned event handler needs to return fast.  Producer/Consumer is the way to go.

Comment: This sounds promising however I am not very familiar with BlockingCollection, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @DelKirksey: There is an excellent example in the MSDN documentation I linked, down at the bottom of the page.

Comment: After an hour of reading and investigating examples I think I may understand how using a BlockingCollection would benefit my current process. My only question (at the moment) is how would I handle multiple, independent (very fast) keystrokes using a BlockingCollection? Or should I handle the keystrokes and then utilize the BlockingCollection solely for processing? @EricJ.